# two element combinations of the elements of a list inside lisp (without duplicates)

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, combinations

From any given list in lisp, I want to get the two element combinations of the elements of that list without having duplicate combinations ( meaning (a b) = (b a) and one should be removed)

So for example if I have a list that is (a b c d),

I want to get ((a b) (a c) (a d) (b c) (b d) (c d))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, I'd use `mapcar` and friends.

```
(defun pair-with (elem lst)
  (mapcar (lambda (a) (list elem a)) lst))

(defun unique-pairs (lst)
  (mapcon (lambda (rest) (pair-with (car rest) (cdr rest)))
          (remove-duplicates lst)))
```

That should let you

```
CL-USER> (unique-pairs (list 1 2 3 4 5))
((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (2 3) (2 4) (2 5) (3 4) (3 5) (4 5))
CL-USER> (unique-pairs (list :a :b :c :a :b :d))
((:C :A) (:C :B) (:C :D) (:A :B) (:A :D) (:B :D))
```

If you're not scared of `loop`, you can also write the second one slightly more clearly as

```
(defun unique-pairs (lst)
  (loop for (a . rest) on (remove-duplicates lst)
        append (pair-with a rest)))
```

instead. I'm reasonably sure that `loop`s `append` directive is more efficient than the function of the same name.

Answer (score 5):

```
(defun combinations (list)
  (loop for (a1 . r1) on list
        nconc (loop for a2 in r1 collect (list a1 a2))))


CL-USER 172 > (combinations '(a b c d))
((A B) (A C) (A D) (B C) (B D) (C D))
```

Answer (score 1):

Scheme solution:

```
(define (lol lst)
  (let outer ((lhs lst))
    (if (null? lhs)
        '()
        (let inner ((rhs (cdr lhs)))
          (if (null? rhs)
              (outer (cdr lhs))
              (cons (list (car lhs) (car rhs)) (inner (cdr rhs))))))))
```

And a Common Lisp translation of same:

```
(defun lol (list)
  (labels ((outer (lhs)
             (and lhs (labels ((inner (rhs)
                                 (if rhs
                                     (cons (list (car lhs) (car rhs))
                                           (inner (cdr rhs)))
                                     (outer (cdr lhs)))))
                        (inner (cdr lhs))))))
    (outer list)))
```

Sorry, I'm not a Common Lisper, so I hope this isn't too ugly. :-)

Comment: Not *too* ugly, just remember that Common Lisp doesn't necessarily optimize tail calls. Some implementations do it, but it's not a guarantee the way that it is in Scheme.

Comment: There are very few tail calls even in my Scheme solution (just the one to `outer`), so it's not really a "cute Scheme loop thing" that I was going for in my solution. :-) But I do like Rainer's explicit loop approach a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Rainer's Joswig answer, in principle, except it doesn't use loops.

```
(defun combinations (list)
  (mapcon (lambda (x) (mapcar (lambda (y) (list (car x) y)) (cdr x))) list))
```

One thing that confuses me about your example is that `(a a)` matches your verbal description of the desired result, but in the example of the result you've excluded it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own initial answer. It might not be completely efficient but it solves the problem.

```
(remove nil (let ((res))
             (dotimes (n (length test-list) res)
                (setq res
                     (append res
                        (let ((res2) (rest-list (remove (nth n test-list) test-list)))
                         (dotimes (m (length rest-list) res2)
                            (setq res2
                                 (append res2
                                   (list (if (< (nth n test-list) (nth m rest-list))
                                         (list (nth n test-list) (nth m rest-list))
                                          nil)))))))))))
```

If the "if statement" on line 9 is removed, the result will include also duplicates and the result will be

```
((a b) (a c) (a d) (a a) (b a) (b c) (b d) (b b) 
 (c a) (c b) (c d) (c c) (d a) (d b) (d c) (d d))
```

Comment: In Lisp programming, you should not access lists via indexing (`nth`), but should instead use `car` and `cdr`. This is because Lisp uses linked lists, so list indexing is O(n). Also `append` is also O(n), and should not be used in a loop if it can be helped at all. See my solution; it uses neither of those.